# Callback when multiple dispatch_async() have finished

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am dispatching a number of actions similar to this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul), 
   ^{
       //Do stuff
   });
```

As soon as all of them have finished executing I want to call another method `[self someMethod];` or dispatch another last block, it doesn't matter which.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dispatch groups or a dispatch barrier.   Both are well documented.

*However*, this kind of concurrency  -- mass dispatch to an asynchronous queue -- is pretty much guaranteed to be slow, resource hungry and very likely lead to your app being jettisoned for memory use.

An asynchronous dispatch *must* spawn a thread if a thread isn't already available to start the processing.  By definition, asynchronous dispatches to the global concurrent queue cannot be throttled in any way as doing so would lead to random deadlocks very quickly when Block A has a dependency on Block B, but Block B is prevented from execution until Block A finishes (for example).

Concurrency should *always* be throttled.

Comment: It is unclear to me how to predict the worst-case number of threads that GCD could create. Is it easy to end up with one thread for each dispatch, even if they don't depend on each other in any way?

Comment: The key is whether the work blocks on anything (a lock, disk or network io, etc...). For purely computational CPU work, GCD will manage things well. Once blocking calls are involved it doesn't have enough information to throttle appropriately.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Even for purely computational work, if you dispatch 100 long running blocks to an asynchronous queue, you'll likely end up with 100 threads.   GCD can't throttle the dispatch of blocks onto asynchronous queues because there is no way for GCD to know what dependencies might exist between them.  Even the dependency API in NSOperationQueue can be considered advisory;  it can't know that operation A blocks B and thus B being throttled from execution because A is running is an invalid state.

Comment: NSOperationQueue actually internally limits concurrency itself some, but that's (as always) an implementation detail subject to change.

Comment: 100 long running computational blocks dispatched onto a global concurrent GCD queue will not create 100 threads, only NCPU threads. Only if one of those threads is blocked in the kernel for a long enough time will a new thread be created, as @Catfish_Man says.

Answer (score 1):

The technique I've used in the past is to make an NSOperationQueue with a limited amount of concurrency (say 3 concurrent operations), then dispatch each block as a NSBlockOperation. Finally, I create a completion NSBlockOperation that is dependent on the completion of all of the other operations. I enqueue all of the operations, including the completion operation. The dependency construct of NSOperations causes the independent ones to complete before the final completion operation is started.

This approach provides the capability to do work once a bunch of other blocks have completed, and it reduces the overall impact of starting a bunch of threads all at once and waiting for them all to complete.

See the addDependency: method of the NSOperation class (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation)

Comment: This works;  one caveat, though.  If you have a bunch of data queued up for processing, don't enqueue all the blocks at once.  It'll be a waste of memory.  Instead, enqueue enough blocks to keep your computation pipeline fully utilized.   That makes overall resource use more efficient while making cancellation less resource intensive, too.